# how to detect the loading tab Id or I want current loading tab id (which is not current selected tab) using chrome.tab methods

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I am building chrome extension i need to detect the current loading tab id's from the current tab (which is not loading but selected tab).
I tried events like onUpdated and  onSelectionChanged these are giving correct results but if i use this things it will trigger for all the browser tabs.
I dont want like that(if use these events i need to change lot of code) ,
So  I want current loading tab id (which is not current tab) using chrome.tab methods

Please help me...

Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was not stated how often (or indeed when) this detection will be required the following should work whenever it's called but will not stay up-to-date by itself (e.g. once tabs have finished loading they may still exist in `loadingTabIds`);

```
// Will store loading tab identifiers
var loadingTabIds = [];
// Retrieve selected tab
chrome.tabs.getSelected(function (selectedTab) {
    // Retrieves all tabs
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            // Excludes selected and loaded tabs
            if (tabs[i].id !== selectedTab.id && tabs[id].status === 'loading') {
                loadingTabIds.push(tabs[i].id);
            }
        }
    });
});
```